# Como modificar campo telefone?

Tags: java, javafx

Eu tenho um componente estilizado com a formatação de telefone, da seguinte forma

> (XX)XXXXX-XXXX

Eu gostaria de saber, como eu posso retirar a parte do DD → **(XX)**, para que o campo fique somente assim: XXXXX-XXXX

Eu tentei modificar os cases, porém não de muito certo.

Meu componente:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class CampoTelefone extends TextField {
    UnaryOperator filter;

    public CampoTelefone() {
        /*Quando o campo é denominado apenas para numeros inteiros*/
        filter = new UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>() {
            @Override
            public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change t) {
                String text = t.getText();
                for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i)) && text.charAt(i) != '-' && text.charAt(i) != '.'
                            && text.charAt(i) != '/' && text.charAt(i) != '(' && text.charAt(i) != ')' && text.charAt(i) != ':') {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return t;
            }
        };

        setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(filter));
        focusedProperty().addListener(e -> mascara(getText(), getText()));

        setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UNDEFINED)
                        || keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.MINUS)
                        || keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SUBTRACT)
                        || keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DIVIDE)
                        || keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.PERIOD)) {
                    setText(getText().replace("-", "").replace("/", "").replace(".", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(":", "").replace(" ", ""));
                }

                if (keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.CONTROL)) {
                    Clipboard clpbrd = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
                    final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                    String rep = clpbrd.getString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
                    content.putString(rep);
                    clpbrd.setContent(content);
                }
            }

        });

        textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String antigo, String novo) -> {

                    if (!(novo).isEmpty() && novo.length() > antigo.length()) {
                        novo = novo.replace(".", "").replace("-", "").replace("/", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(",", "").replace(":", "").replace(" ", "");
                        //antigo = antigo.replace(".", "").replace("-", "").replace("/", "").replace(",", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
                        mascara(novo, antigo);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void mascara(String novo, String antigo) {
        switch (novo.length()) {
            case 1:
                setText("(" + novo);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 2:
                setText("(" + novo + ")");
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 3:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 3));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 4:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 4));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 5:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 5));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 6:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 6) + "-");
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 7:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 6) + "-" + novo.substring(6, 7));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 8:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 6) + "-" + novo.substring(6, 8));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 9:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 6) + "-" + novo.substring(6, 9));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 10:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 6) + "-" + novo.substring(6, 10));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });
                break;
            case 11:
                setText("(" + novo.substring(0, 2) + ")" + novo.substring(2, 7) + "-" + novo.substring(7, 11));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 12:
                setText(antigo);
                break;
            default:
                setText(antigo);

        }
    }

    public void setValor(Object valor) {
        setText(String.valueOf(valor)); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public Object getValor() {

        return ((!getText().isEmpty())
                ? (getText()).replace("-", "").replace(".", "").replace("/", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "") : "");
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {

        }

        if (start < 0 || end > getLength()) {
            //throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return getContent().get(0, 0);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Pra isso você vai ter que sobrecarregar a classe do texto de telefone e fazer sua customização.

Comment: Tem que ser feito o ajuste nessa classe ou pode propor uma outra solução?

Comment: @Renan pode propor outra, qualquer sugestão é bem - vinda !

Answer (score 0):

Basta alterar o método `mascara`. O `switch` verifica o tamanho da string, a depender do tamanho, os caracteres da máscara vão sendo adicionados.

No método antigo, os cases estão adicionando os parênteses nos 2 primeiros dígitos. Basta remover essa lógica.

Nos cases 1, 2 e 3, nenhuma ação precisa ser tomada, basta setar o texto. A partir do `case` 4 é necessário adicionar um hífen depois do quarto dígito. No `case` 9 é necessário adicionar um hífen depois do quinto dígito.

```
public void mascara(String novo, String antigo) {
        switch (novo.length()) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                setText(novo);
                break;
            case 4:
                setText(novo+"-");
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 5:
                setText(novo.substring(0, 4) + "-" + novo.substring(4, 5));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 6:
                setText(novo.substring(0, 4) + "-" + novo.substring(4, 6));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 7:
                setText(novo.substring(0, 4) + "-" + novo.substring(4, 7));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 8:
                setText(novo.substring(0, 4) + "-" + novo.substring(4, 8));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            case 9:
                setText(novo.substring(0, 5) + "-" + novo.substring(5, 9));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    end();
                });

                break;
            default:
                setText(antigo);
        }
    }
```